# Python - keyword reading program, having trouble removing punctuation

Tags: python

Hi have been playing with a simple program that reads in text and identify's keywords where the initial letter is capitalised. The issue I am having is that the program will not remove punctuation from words, what I mean by that is, Frodo Frodo. Frodo, are coming up as different entries rather than the same. I tried using import string and playing around with punctuation but it did not work.

Below is my code and the text i used was from http://www.angelfire.com/rings/theroaddownloads/fotr.pdf (copied into a txt document called novel.txt).
Thanks Again

```
by_word = {}
with open ('novel.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    for word in line.strip().split():
      if word[0].isupper():
        if word in by_word:
          by_word[word] += 1
        else:
          by_word[word] = 1

by_count = []
for word in by_word:
  by_count.append((by_word[word], word))

by_count.sort()
by_count.reverse()

for count, word in by_count[:100]:
  print(count, word)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Tried using the above solution first, but it didn't seem to work with my implementation, I possibly could have been doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this below will work for you as expected:

```
import string
exclude = set(string.punctuation)

by_word = {}
with open ('novel.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    for word in line.strip().split():
      if word[0].isupper():
        word = ''.join(char for char in word if char not in exclude)
        if word in by_word:
          by_word[word] += 1
        else:
          by_word[word] = 1

by_count = []
for word in by_word:
  by_count.append((by_word[word], word))

by_count.sort()
by_count.reverse()

for count, word in by_count[:100]:
  print(count, word)
```

It will remove all of

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

from `word`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, to strip punctuation, split using a regex,

```
for word in line.strip().split():
```

can be changed to

```
for word in re.split('[,.;]',line.strip()):
```

where, first argument in `[]` contains all the punctuation marks. This uses the `re` module, https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split.

Comment: Thanks that seems to have removed the punctuation but am now getting, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joshr\Desktop\Key-word reader.py", line 7, in <module>
    if word[0].isupper():
IndexError: string index out of range - I understand what this error is trying to say but surely as each list is made up of only one object there should be no issue with index 0.